# db2 creating proxy user account

Tags: db2

SQL server has an option to create proxy user accounts with the statement 
    CREATE USER proxyUser WITHOUT LOGIN;

I couldn't find much help on internet on getting the db2 (v8) equivalent of this. I'm not sure whether this is possible, if yes please let me know how.

The scenario where i want to use this is as follows.
I have table with ~8 million records which gets updated daily. Before the inserts happen, few records are deleted from the table and the number is ~2 million. Since these deletes need not be logged, we decided on setting off Logging during the deletes. Since our credentials do not have alter table rights, we decided to put the ALTER and DELETE statements in a script and  and execute the script using the proxy account irrespective of what user executes the SP.

I foud this article which closely describes the scenario which i described above. The differences are that i need to do this on db2 and i need to do deletes without logging them.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2583/grant-truncate-table-permissions-in-sql-server-without-alter-table/

Thanks
Arjun

Comment: What DB2 platform? z/OS?

Comment: It's linux, don't know the specific OS, it's DB2 version 8. I connect using putty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work basically in the same manner in DB2, with a few exceptions. Firstly, there's no `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement in DB2 8.2 (and there's no DB2 version 8 on Linux). Secondly, there are no *database users* in DB2 -- all users are defined externally in the operating system, so there's no `CREATE USER` statement either.

All statements in a stored procedure, except dynamic SQL, are executed with the authorization of the procedure creator.

So, using the authorized ID, e.g. the database administrator's ID, create the stored procedure that does what you need (ALTER, DELETE, whatever), then grant the EXECUTE privilege on that procedure to whoever needs to run it.

Comment: thanks for the reply . So if i create a script with alter table in it and then have the DBA execute it to create the script ,have him provide execute rights to me and then if i run the script, it'll execute without any "permission denied on table" errors ? i don't have rights for any ddl statements i only have rights to execute dml statements.

Comment: PS: I haven't marked it as an accepted answer yet since i had the clarification to be done. I tried marking the reply as useful but looks like i don't have the required points for the same..

Comment: No, it will not work that way with a script. Script is just a series of statements, executed with the authority of whoever runs the script. What you need is a **stored procedure**, which is compiled, saved, and later executed using the authority of whoever runs the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

Comment: Hi, what i meant was a script to create the procedure with the alter table commands. Thanks for the clarification.